# Solving three simultaneous equations most efficiently for two variables

Tags: numerical-methods, algorithms

I am working on a triangulation algorithm to be used with an 8-bit microcontroller using UWB RFID. I will have two unknowns $x$ and $y$ for the item I am tracking, but I need to use three equations to solve it since only using two will give two solutions.

These are the equations:

$$(x-a_{0x})^{2} + (y-a_{0y})^{2} = d_{0}^{2}\\
(x-a_{1x})^{2} + (y-a_{1y})^{2} = d_{1}^{2}\\
(x-a_{2x})^{2} + (y-a_{2y})^{2} = d_{2}^{2}$$

Here $a_{nx}$, $a_{ny}$ and $d_n$ are known.

I have two issues. First, since this will be using RFID, the values that I will use will not give an "exact" value, so the method used to solve this will need to be an approximation.

Second, since this is on an 8-bit processor, I need to use the most efficient method possible to solve this equation set.

Could I have some suggestions on what numerical solving algorithms I should try?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

So for example, if I have this set of equations as the "true" set:
$$(x--6)^{2} + (y-9)^{2} = 25\\
(x-6)^{2} + (y-9)^{2} = 73\\
(x)^{2} + (y)^{2} = 40$$
The exact value of $(x,y)$ is $(-2,6)$.

But since the know values are gathered from my RFID chip, they will never be "exact" and instead, I could have an equation set like:

$$(x--6.01)^{2} + (y-9.6)^{2} = 25.5\\
(x-6.05)^{2} + (y-9)^{2} = 72.8\\
(x)^{2} + (y)^{2} = 40.5$$

So the solving algorithm needs to be able to give a best approximation for the equation. Maybe using ordinary squares?

Comment: If you subtract pairs of these equations from each other you will end up with linear equations in $x$ and $y$.

Comment: @amd but that won't work if my values for my knowns are not exact. Since solving it linearly requires an exact answer no?

Comment: @amd See me updated question please for some elaboration

Comment: The last set of equations has no real solution though.

Comment: @JohnGlenn I know, that's the point. Is there no way to calculate the closest intersection point?

Comment: @KyleHunter: linearity or non-linearity of the equations has nothing to do with the fact that the data is inaccurate.

Comment: @KyleHunter: you probably mean "ordinary *least* squares". Don't hope that using 3 points instead of 2 will yield a dramatic improvement in precision.

Comment: Noise doesn’t make a substantial difference to the method. You might, for instance, solve all three pairs of intersections and then compute the centroid. The critical thing is to decide on how good an approximation you want vs. computational complexity.

Comment: @amd For the subtracting pairs that you suggested, how do you get an approximate answer for the equations even when there is no actual solution from a set of linear equations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference of any pair of the circle equations is the equation of a line that passes through their intersection points. If the measurements are exact, these three lines are coincident, in which case the common intersection of the three circles can be found by computing the intersection of any two of them. It turns out that in the presence of noise these lines remain coincident, so their intersection can be used as a fairly quick and dirty estimate of the true intersection.

The equation of the line through the intersection points of circles $i$ and $j$ is $$2(a_{ix}-a_{jx})x+2(a_{iy}-a_{jy})y+(d_i^2-a_{ix}^2-a_{iy}^2)-(d_j^2-a_{jx}^2-a_{jy}^2) = 0,$$ or in homogeneous vector notation, $$\begin{align} \mathbf l_{ij} &= [2(a_{ix}-a_{jx}):2(a_{iy}-a_{jy}):(d_i^2-a_{ix}^2-a_{iy}^2)-(d_j^2-a_{jx}^2-a_{jy}^2)] \\
&= [2a_{ix}:2a_{iy}:d_i^2-a_{ix}^2-a_{iy}^2] - [2a_{jx}:2a_{jy}:d_j^2-a_{jx}^2-a_{jy}^2] \\
&= \mathbf m_i - \mathbf m_j. \end{align}$$ The intersection of lines $\mathbf l_{ij}$ and $\mathbf l_{jk}$ is $$\begin{align} \mathbf l_{ij} \times \mathbf l_{jk} &= (\mathbf m_i - \mathbf m_j)\times(\mathbf m_j-\mathbf m_k) \\
&= (\mathbf m_i\times\mathbf m_j)+(\mathbf m_j\times\mathbf m_k)+(\mathbf m_k\times\mathbf m_j). \end{align}$$ It’s not hard to see that the three pairwise intersections yield the same point. To dehomogenize, divide through by the last component of its homogeneous coordinates.

Applying this to your perturbed example produces $$\begin{align} \mathbf m_0 &= [-12.02 : 19.2 : -102.7801] \\ \mathbf m_1 &= [12.1 : 18 : -44.8025] \\ \mathbf m_2 &= [0 : 0 : 40.5] \end{align}$$ and $$(\mathbf m_0\times\mathbf m_1)+(\mathbf m_1\times\mathbf m_2)+(\mathbf m_2\times\mathbf m_0) = [941.2338 : -2759.02526 : -448.68],$$ which dehomogenizes to $(-2.09778, 6.1492)$, which is pretty close to the result in other answers.

Comment: If you’ve got limited numeric range, watch out for overflow when computing these cross products. You can rescale the $\mathbf m$’s if necessary before plunging into that part of the computation. Also, it might be less expensive to compute the cross product of two of the $\mathbf l$ lines instead of the three $\mathbf m$ cross products.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the equation to be
$$f_i=(x-x_i)^2+(y-y_i)^2-d_i^2$$ What you need to do is to minimize, with respect to $x$ and $y$,
$$\Phi=\sum_{i=1}^3 f_i^2$$ and, as usual, you need starting guesses.

To get *estimates* of them, as already commented by amd, subtract them to get
$$2(x_1-x_2)x+2(y_1-y_2) y=(x_1^2+y_1^2-d_1^2)-(x_2^2+y_2^2-d_2^2)\tag 1$$
$$2(x_1-x_3)x+2(y_1-y_3) y=(x_1^2+y_1^2-d_1^2)-(x_3^2+y_3^2-d_3^2)\tag 2$$

Let 
$$A_1=2(x_1-x_2)\qquad  B_1=2(y_1-y_2)\qquad C_1=(x_1^2+y_1^2-d_1^2)-(x_2^2+y_2^2-d_2^2)$$
$$A_2=2(x_1-x_3)\qquad  B_2=2(y_1-y_3)\qquad C_2=(x_1^2+y_1^2-d_1^2)-(x_3^2+y_3^2-d_3^2)$$
Solve for $(x,y)$ to get 
$$x=\frac{B_1\, C_2-B_2\, C_1}{A_2\, B_1-A_1\, B_2}\qquad y=\frac{A_2\, C_1-A_1\, C_2}{A_2 \,B_1-A_1\, B_2}\tag 3$$
Now, back to $\Phi$, compute its partial derivatives
$$\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial x}=4\sum_{i=1}^3 (x-x_i) \left((x-x_i)^2+(y-y_i)^2-d_i^2 \right)$$
$$\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial y}=4\sum_{i=1}^3 (y-y_i) \left((x-x_i)^2+(y-y_i)^2-d_i^2 \right)$$ and set them equal to $0$. You can solve them using Newton-Raphson method since the first step will give you could estimates.

Using your data, the first step will give $x=-2.09778$ and $y=6.14920$. Doing the second step, you should get $x=-2.03599$ and $y=6.15465$. You can see how close the final results are when compared to the estimates.

**Remark**

If I may, I would like to comment : what you measure are the $d_i$'s and not their squares. This means that the equations should be instead
$$g_i=\sqrt{(x-x_i)^2+(y-y_i)^2}-d_i$$ and you would need to to minimize, with respect to $x$ and $y$,
$$\Psi=\sum_{i=1}^3 g_i^2$$ which is more tedious but perfectly doable.
$$\frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial x}=2\sum_{i=1}^3 \frac{(x-x_i)
   \left(\sqrt{(x-x_i)^2+(y-y_i)^2}-d_i\right)}{\sqrt{(x-x_i)^2+(y-y_i)^2}}$$
$$\frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial y}=2\sum_{i=1}^3 \frac{(y-y_i)
   \left(\sqrt{(x-x_i)^2+(y-y_i)^2}-d_i\right)}{\sqrt{(x-x_i)^2+(y-y_i)^2}}$$

For the estimates, keep the previous procedure. Working with $\Psi$, you should get $x=-2.08559$ and $y=6.16485$. Not very different but not the same and more consistent with the principle of [data reconciliation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_validation_and_reconciliation) (which is what you are doing).

Comment: Why would I do the second step? Is there a situation when the first and second step would diverge from each other a more significant amount?

Comment: Also, for the first step. How does that work? How do you get an approximate answer for the equations even when there is no actual solution from a set of linear equations?

Comment: @KyleHunter.  The second step is to polish the solution of the first step (solution given by $(3)$). This is required because, as said, you measure $d_i$ and not $d_i^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, you want a best estimate point for the intersection when there is really no actual intersection

---

You can try to adjust the radii of the circles until you have an actual common intersection point.

Modify the set of equations to include $k$ as shown below: $$\begin{align} (x+6.01)^2+(y-9.6)^2&=\left(k+\sqrt{25.5}\right)^2\\ (x-6.05)^2+(y-9)^2&=\left(k+\sqrt{72.8}\right)^2\\ x^2+y^2&=\left(k+\sqrt{40.5}\right)^2 \end{align}$$

Solving for $k,x$ and $y$, you get two solutions, but only one is meaningful: $$\{\{k\to -13.3504,x\to 1.78746,y\to 6.75391\},\color{red}{\{k\to 0.140533,x\to -2.13868,y\to 6.14284\}\}}$$

This is quick and doesn't really involve calculus

---

The next method is tedious, and maybe redundant.

We define: $$g_1(x,y):=(x+6.01)^2+(y-9.6)^2-25.5\\ g_2(x,y):=(x-6.05)^2+(y-9)^2-72.8\\ g_3(x,y):=x^2 + y^2 - 40.5$$

Try to solve the different intersection points of two circles closest to the expected intersection point of the 3 circles, i.e: $$\begin{align} \text{Solve} &g_1(x,y)=0\land g_2(x,y)=0\\ &g_1(x,y)=0\land g_3(x,y)=0\\ &g_2(x,y)=0\land g_3(x,y)=0\\ \end{align}$$

You get these points, however, only those in red is relevant: $$g_1(x,y)\land g_2(x,y): \{\color{red}{\{x\to -2.08412,y\to 6.42393\}},\{x\to -1.78826,y\to 12.3707\}\}\\ g_1(x,y)\land g_3(x,y):\{\{x\to -3.9506,y\to 4.98927\},\color{red}{\{x\to -2.76216,y\to 5.73328\}}\}\\ g_2(x,y)\land g_3(x,y):\{\color{red}{\{x\to -1.95803,y\to 6.05526\}},\{x\to 6.34637,y\to 0.472857\}\}$$

Now you want to find $(x_i,y_i)$ where the total sum of the lengths from each of the relevant point above to $(x_i,y_i)$ is minimized. Define: $$a_x=-1.95803,a_y=6.05526\\ b_x=-2.08412,b_y=6.42393\\ c_x=-2.76216,c_y=5.73328$$

Now we want to minimize: $$m(x,y):=\sqrt{\left(x-a_x\right){}^2+\left(y-a_y\right){}^2}+\sqrt{\left(x-b_x\right){}^2+\left(y-b_y\right){}^2}+\sqrt{\left(x-c_x\right){}^2+\left(y-c_y\right){}^2}$$ Using numerical methods, we get that $m(x,y)$ (at $m(x,y)=1.2207$) is minimized when: $$\{x\to -2.08342,y\to 6.12726\}$$

Now we see that the first method is fairly close to this numerical answer.

Comment: I think that first method will work perfectly. Since I can then solve it linearly, it should be very efficient as well. Thanks!

Comment: Actually @JohnGlen, what method would you use to solve it? I forgot, it isn't linear

Comment: Are you familiar with multivariable Newton-Raphson? This uses linear approximation, which means it can be solved by hand.

Comment: I'm not very confident with the first method, though. Because the adjustment $k$ might be abnormally large, which might skew your approximations. But I assume that the circles are _always_ fairly "close", right?

Comment: Yeah, they should be fairly close. I'm going to test your method and also amd/Claude Leibovici's with subtracting pairs. I think the latter might be a safer approximation?

Answer (score 0):

In the first place, you should work with the pairwise subtracted equations, as they reduce to linear ones and make the solution unique, while sparing square roots. You will get three straight lines approximately coincident.

For a simple estimate, I would take the intersection of the two lines *that are the less parallel*. To check this, you can compare the cosine of the angle between normals,

$$\frac{a_ia_j+b_ib_j}{\sqrt{a_i^2+b_i^2}\sqrt{a_j^2+b_j^2}}$$ (assuming equations of the form $ax+by+c=0$) and pick the smallest.

In other words, and to avoid the square roots, take the smallest of

$$(a_ia_j+b_ib_j)^2(a_k^2+b_k^2).$$

---

If you want to "improve" the value by least-squares, a possible formulation is to minimize the total discrepancy between the radii and the distances to the centers.

$$\sum_k\left(\sqrt{(x-x_k)^2+(y-y_k)^2}-d_k\right)^2.$$

This leads to a nasty system of two nonlinearequations
$$\begin{cases}\sum_k\dfrac{x-x_k}{\sqrt{(x-x_k)^2+(y-y_k)^2}}\left(\sqrt{(x-x_k)^2+(y-y_k)^2}-d_k\right)=0,\\
\sum_k\dfrac{y-y_k}{\sqrt{(x-x_k)^2+(y-y_k)^2}}\left(\sqrt{(x-x_k)^2+(y-y_k)^2}-d_k\right)=0
\end{cases}$$

which I don't think should be used.

Without much loss, it can be approximated as

$$\begin{cases}\sum_k\dfrac{x-x_k}{d_k}\left(\sqrt{(x-x_k)^2+(y-y_k)^2}-d_k\right)=0,\\
\sum_k\dfrac{y-y_k}{d_k}\left(\sqrt{(x-x_k)^2+(y-y_k)^2}-d_k\right)=0
\end{cases}$$

or

$$\begin{cases}\sum_k\dfrac{x-x_k}{d_k}\dfrac{(x-x_k)^2+(y-y_k)^2-d_k^2}{d_k}=0,\\
\sum_k\dfrac{y-y_k}{d_k}\dfrac{(x-x_k)^2+(y-y_k)^2-d_k^2}{d_k}=0
\end{cases}$$

but this doesn't seem to be enough to make it tractable.

IMO, this approach is a dead end due to its computational complexity vs. the modest gain in accuracy.

Comment: Hi Yves ! All of that solves wihtout any problem if you generate estimates using my first step. Then Newton-Raphson converges in a couple of iterations.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: Hi Claude. Of course it does. But this needs to run on an 8 bits microcontroller. On such processors, even integer divisions are terrible. All floating-point arithmetic must be emulated. I suggested a very low cost implementation.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: But think for a second: what will you win by using least-squares on three points rather than two ? All this machinery seems total overkill to me (I bet a cost at least 10000 times larger than simple line intersection). IMO, the reasonable way is to choose the pair of equations that give the best numerical stability.

Comment: I must confess that I missed the point about  an 8 bits microcontroller. Do you thing that $(3)$ is my answer could be prohibitive ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: no, your 3 is indeed the line intersection method as described by amd (and that I mentioning in my answer). My point is that least-squares improvement would be foolishness.